# Python sparse intersection of matrices non-zero values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two sparse* adjacency matrices `A1` and `A2` of `type 'numpy.int64'`.
The nodes of the corresponding graphs are labeled by integers and the indices of the matrices correspond to these nodes (the matrix value being the link weight between the nodes).

I'm trying to compute a similarity measure between the graphs. To do this I need to find the adjacency matrix for the subgraph of each graph, which contains the nodes common to both graphs.
Nothing about the equals sizes of the matrices, or common nodes between them is assured.

The result should be the same adjacency matrices with values for nodes not in both graphs equal to zero.

Example:

```
A1:
array([[  0, 1, 2, 1],
       [  1, 0, 0, 0],
       [  2, 0, 0, 0],
       [  1, 0, 0, 0]])
A2:
array([[  0, 0, 1],
       [  0, 0, 0],
       [  1, 0, 0]])
```

Outcome:

```
A1':
array([[  0, 0, 2, 0],
       [  0, 0, 0, 0],
       [  2, 0, 0, 0],
       [  0, 0, 0, 0]])
A2':
array([[  0, 0, 1],
       [  0, 0, 0],
       [  1, 0, 0]])
```

The size of matrices I'm using are on order of 10^5 X 10^5. The resulting size doesn't matter, I'll slice down the size of the smallest afterwards.
I'll be repeating this operation many times and so speed is important.

Attempts so far:

I can get the list of common nodes by:

```
np.intersect1d(A1.nonzero()[0], A2.nonzero()[0])
```

But I can't find a way of using this as a filter to map the values for indices not in this list to 0.

*I don't think I necessarily need to use sparse though is very preferable for scalability later.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, based on the example you have provided, you can simply use the `numpy.in1d` method to give you a boolean array *indices*, for example

```
A1 = np.array([[  0, 1, 2, 1],
       [  1, 0, 0, 0],
       [  2, 0, 0, 0],
       [  1, 0, 0, 0]])
A2 = np.array([[  0, 0, 1],
       [  0, 0, 0],
       [  1, 0, 0]])

idx = np.in1d(A1,A2).reshape(A1.shape)
A1[idx] = 0
print(A1)

# prints
[[0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

For sparse matrices, the right solution depends on which sparse format you are using. If you are using `csr` or `csc` formats then you can apply the same technique on the coefficients `(V_IJ)` of the matrices `A1.data` and then use resulting array `(idx)` to modify the corresponding indices `(I and J)` i.e. `A1.indices` and `A1.indptr`.